# How to not lose element focus when click on element's adorner

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox that is associated with an Adorner. However when I give the TextBox keyboard focus, and then click the adorner, it removes the TextBox's keyboard focus (LostKeyboardFocus event). I need the TextBox to keep keyboard focus when I click the adorner (which is just a blue box surrounding the TextBox.

I don't think I can screenshot the visual assets or the snoop with the class hierarchy. Don't know how those rules work.

But basically it is

Grid

> MyTextbox

AdornerLayer

> ResizeAdorner { AdornedElement = MyTextBox }

where the ResizeAdorner just extends the WPF Adorner class.

One option I'm considering is handling the GotFocus event in the ResizeAdorner, and manually Focus()ing the adorned Element again.

Comment: You should post minimal xaml. I have TextBoxes in my applications and they do not lose focus when the window is resized.

Comment: Alright, I added a bit more explanation. I don't really know how much I can put